# JS & CSS dropdown menu codes effecting full website codes

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am using multiple colomn dropdown menu which has JS and css and this scripts. When I install this menu everything in my website got changed. I know its because of the scripts only. All buttons size increase, all text size increase, some previous java script not working. Please let me know why is it ... [Click Here for Website](http://www.fedri.com) Everything got changed. Please help me.

Comment: Most likely because the new css is overriding some styles in your main one (I'm saying this without clicking to your website) Put it _before_ and see

Comment: Please let me where to put the code. I am a new bee, pleaes support me.

Comment: Show us what you added. Show us what you've tried. Show us some effort.

Comment: Ryan, its because of the help like you people this problem solve jsut only remain JS problem. Dear I am not from software filed, may be its easy for you but its difficult for the one who dont know codes. You dont know how much I am strugging for running this site. I am electrical engg and i am daily reading codes... anyhow thnx for yuor comments.

Comment: What did I just read? "I'm not a software developer, I don't know how to do this. Running this site is difficult". Maybe you should learn how to write code and you won't have this problem. StackOverflow is not a "coder for hire" website. You just admitted to letting SO users write the majority of your code. Constructively; I suggest you pick up a few books on front end development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the menu's CSS has generic selectors in it. Look at the file http://www.fedri.com/css/dcmegamenu.css and you will see the following right at the top of the file.

```
ul{list-style:none;}

body {font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;}
h2 {font: normal 26px Arial, sans-serif; padding: 20px 0; margin: 0 0 30px 0;}
```

Comment: yes I saw this before and I delete all three but some of the functions are not working if I did so. Do I have to modify it?? please tell me I dont know more.. and about JS also. all buttons got increased.. Please suggest uru answer

Comment: please let me know do I have to modify this code or to delete this?? Please suggest me the new code. I dont know writing codes..

Comment: Um, you open up the file and remove the lines??

Comment: Yes I remove the lines, if you see now there are some dots spreads on the left side of my menu.  Even I was having this line which I deleted before body,html,div,blockquote,img,label,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,form,a,fieldset,input,th,td{border:0;outline:none;margin:0;padding:0;}

Comment: So you need to apply a rule to the lis in the menu to replace the ul line you removed. `.mega-menu {list-style:none;}` Learn CSS if you are doing web development. :)

Comment: Dear epascarello, you can please tell me the codes, I dont know...even JS also not working

Comment: Thanks epascarello its working but JS is still the problem. Please click http://www.fe dri.com/clubs.php (just remove space) username is testuser and password is testtest scpriting for the tab of new community, popular community and your community is not working after insatll the menu.. please sugeest this also.. thanks.